# Java, Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException:

Tags: java

I have the following problem while I'm trying to run in command line jar file assembled in Maven in ItelliJ IDEA.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:801)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:799)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:654)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:551)

*Is there anyone who knows what causes this SecurityException and how to solve this?
It seems I tried everything that discussed on this forum but, regretfully nothing has helped...

I am using: Windows 10, Java 9.0.4, Maven 3.5.3, ItelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4*

Here is pom.xml file:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots-meta</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>crypto</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jumpmind.symmetric.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sat4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.sat4j.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>SimpleBot</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.9</source>
                <target>1.9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance.